# Getting syntax error when I run the following pip install paramiko

Tags: python, pip

I have `python 2.7.13` for windows 7.  I recently installed `python 3.8` in a separate folder `(c:\Python38)`.
I tried to install `contextlib` or `paramiko` modules, but i get the following error.

> C:\Python38>pip install paramiko       File "C:\Python38\Lib\site.py",
>   line 178    file=sys.stderr)
>          ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   PYTHONPATH=C:\Python38;C:\Python38\Lib;C:\Python38\DLLs;C:\Python38\Lib\lib-tk

What am I missing?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you using the python3.8 executable to install the modules? looks like it's using the 2.7 version instead

Comment: I had to modify my path and PYTHONPATH statement.  now it works.

Comment: @PatrickShapard then close the issue

Comment: I'm new to asking questions on SO.  Where do you go to close this question.  thanks

Comment: @PatrickShapard you can write your own answer and mark it as the right one. Then, if someone faces the same problem, they will easily find the solution